# Como comparar o dia de um LocalDate no CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, criteria

Tenho uma entidade que tem um campo LocalDate.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="feriado")
    public class Feriado implements Serializable{

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;

      @NotNull
      @Column(nullable=false,unique=true)
      @Convert(converter=LocalDateConverter.class)
      private LocalDate feriado;

      @NotNull @Size(min=5,max=100)
      @Column(nullable=false,length=100)
      private String descricao;

      @Column(name="dia_fixo",nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT", length = 1)
      private Boolean diaFixo;

      // get and sets

   }
```

Estou fazendo uma consulta utilizando CriteriaBuilder e necessito filtrar o atributo **feriado** pelo dia

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

Root<Feriado> root = cq.from(Feriado.class);

cq.select(cb.count(root));

//Parametros
List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<>();

Predicate filtroData = 
    cb.equal(root.<LocalDate>get("feriado"), dia);
```

A duvida é exatamente na ultima linha

**Predicate filtroData = 
        cb.equal(root.get("feriado"), dia);**

Como obter apenas o dia do campo Feriado ?
Ou seja, obter o valor do método getDayOfMonth() de um LocalDate  com o criteria?